# What is the difference between "into" and "in" when cutting something

Tags: grammar

How can I explain the logical meaning of the difference between into and in when cutting something.  For example, 'Cut the peach into 3 pieces' vs 'Cut the peach in half'  Thank you!

Comment: This question is better asked on [ell.se]

Comment: Chose a better example. This doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

*`Into`* and *`in`* are both prepositions with slight changes; `into` implies objects/locations while `in` is far more general. The main difference in your peach-cutting scenarios is that the first instance uses a *`noun`* form whereas the second deals with an *`adjective`*.

> Cut the peach into 3 **pieces**

"Piece" is a noun, whilst...

> ... in half

"half" is an adjective.

By the same logic, take a look at the following that conveys similar meanings:

> Cut the peach into **halves** or **thirds**. (`into` + n.)

Comment: Good answer. *In half* seems to be an adjectival phrase, which only applies if there is just one peach.

Comment: It looks like *different sizes* is a Noun Phrase though ...

Comment: @Araucaria I mislead myself into thinking: "peaches `of` or `in` different sizes". Omitted to prevent confusion. Thanks for spotting it!